# Автоматизация ротации и агрегации логов

Tags: debian, логирование

Есть сервер на python работающий в несколько процессов под debian
Каждый процесс ведет свой файл логов
Объем логов примерно 50-60к строк в день для всех процессов вместе

Задача:
1)раз в несколько минут объединять содержимое этих файлов один общий
2)раз в сутки архивировать этот общий файл и заливать на удаленное хранилище
Какую связку инструментов лучше всего использовать чтобы автоматизировать этот процесс?

Answer (score 1):

> Каждый процесс ведет свой файл логов

Как я догадываюсь, это делается из-за невозможности сразу писать в один лог?

В таком случае используйте [сислог](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html), а для архивации и отправки - [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Рассмотрим на примере.

Настроим сислог на запись лог-сообщений из скрипта `daemon.py` в отдельный файл:

```
echo -e ':syslogtag,contains,"daemon.py" /var/log/daemon.py.log\n& stop' | sudo tee /etc/rsyslog.d/10-daemon.py.conf
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

В результате мы создадим отдельную конфигурацию, которая будет ловить сообщения из скрипта `daemon.py` и записывать их в файл `/var/log/daemon.py.log`.

Теперь сделаем простой скрипт записи в сислог `daemon.py`:

```
import syslog
syslog.syslog('Hello from python')
```

Запустим пару раз и проверим:

```
python daemon.py
python daemon.py
cat /var/log/daemon.py.log
```

Выведется одна запись, так как сислог не пишет "повторы" одного и того же сообщения (это можно отключить): `Aug 25 17:08:16 totalpusher-desktop daemon.py: Hello from python`.

Отлично, теперь у нас есть лог файл, в который можно писать сразу в несколько потоков.

Теперь нужно настроить сжатие, ротацию и отправку логов на удаленную машину. В примере я буду слать на эту же машину по `ssh` (`totalpusher@localhost`) в каталог `/tmp`.

Для этого нужно подправить файл `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` (Debian) или `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` (CentOS), добавив в конец следующее:

```
# Такой строкой определяем шаблон файлов, которые будут обрабатываться. у нас - один файл.
# А можно, например, и так: `/var/log/daemon.*.log`
/var/log/daemon.py.log
{
  # количество архивов, самые старые - удаляются:
  rotate 7
  # ротация - каждый день
  daily
  # если файла не будет - не считать за ошибку
  missingok
  # не обрабатывать пустые файлы
  notifempty
  # включить сжатие
  compress
  # эта опция откладывает сжатие до следующего раза
  delaycompress
  # выполнить секцию postrotate только один раз, а не для каждого лог файла из шаблона
  sharedscripts
  # эта секция будет выполнена сразу после ротации лога
  postrotate
          # это заставляет сислог переоткрыть файлы, так как логротейт перемещает "по кругу" файлы,
          # а сислог может продолжить писать в открытый файл, который уже был перемещен
          /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
          # шлем все накопленные логи на удаленную машину
          # `|| true` добавляется, чтобы при ошибке вся строка все равно возвращала код ошибки 0
          scp /var/log/daemon.py.log* totalpusher@localhost:/tmp/ || true
  endscript
}
```

Проверим правильность работы в "debug" режиме:

```
sudo logrotate -vdf /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

Не должно возникнуть серьезных ошибок. Теперь запустим в `force` режиме и проверим содержимое "удаленного" хранилища (у меня в примере это `localhost`):

```
sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
ls -la /tmp/daemon.py.log*
```

В результатах будет файл `/tmp/daemon.py.log.1`, который является еще не сжатым логом (из-за опции `delaycompress`). Каждый новый день заставит перемещаться файл по циклу:

`daemon.py.log.1` => `daemon.py.log.2.gz` (уже в сжатом виде) => `daemon.py.log.3.gz` => ... => `daemon.py.log.6.gz` => удаление

Сислог и логротейт - гибкие программы. Поизучайте их, чтобы написать конфигурацию под свои задачи.

Теперь про `scp` из секции `postrotate`. Так как логротейт работает под `root`, заранее надо позаботиться о его правах для доступа к удаленной машине. Можно сделать так:

```
# заходим под root
sudo su
# создаем связку ключей (если ключи уже есть, делать не надо):
ssh-keygen
# копируем публичный ключ на удаленную машину, в моем примере - это та же самая машина
ssh-copy-id totalpusher@localhost
```

Теперь все автоматизировано, ура!

PS. Сислог можно сразу слать по UDP на удаленную машину. Посмотрите документацию, возможно это то-что вам нужно.